# Pandas: is this the most right way to get the most closed date from index?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have some data like below:

```py
data = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], index=['2021/01/01', '2020/01/02', '2020/01/04', '2020/01/05'])
```

and I want to get the closed index relative to a passing date parameter:

```py
def handle(data, end_date):
  pass

handle(data, '2020/01/03')
```

I want to know, is the following code the most proper method:

```py
def handle(data, end_date):
  end_date = data.index[data.index <= end_date][-1]
  print(end_date) # '2020/01/02'
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your solution is good, here ia alternative with [`Index.searchsorted`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.searchsorted.html):

```
data = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], index=['2021/01/01', '2020/01/02', 
                                      '2020/01/04', '2020/01/05'])
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index)
```

---

```
def handle(data, end_date):
     return data.index[data.index.searchsorted(end_date, side='right') - 1]


print (handle(data, '2020/01/02'))
2020-01-02 00:00:00
print (handle(data, '2020/01/03'))
2020-01-02 00:00:00
```

For generally solution:

```
def handle(data, end_date):
  end_date = data.index[data.index <= end_date]
  return end_date[-1] if len(end_date) > 0 else 'no match'

print (handle(data, '2020/01/02'))
2020-01-02 00:00:00
print (handle(data, '2020/01/03'))
2020-01-02 00:00:00
print (handle(data, '2020/01/01'))
no match
```

---

```
def handle(data, end_date):
      idx = data.index.searchsorted(end_date, side='right') - 1
      return  data.index[idx] if idx != -1 else 'no match'
 

print (handle(data, '2020/01/02'))
2020-01-02 00:00:00
print (handle(data, '2020/01/03'))
2020-01-02 00:00:00
print (handle(data, '2020/01/01'))
no match
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I find the specific format 'yyyy/mm/dd' could also be sorted, so maybe it doesn't need to be converted to datetime.

Comment: @Run - My opinion - working well with strings `yyyy/mm/dd`, if large data better convert to datetimes if performance is important.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest using binary search if you care about the efficiency on a large dataset.

```py
from bisect import bisect_left

data = ['2021/01/01', '2020/01/02', '2020/01/04', '2020/01/05']

data = sorted(data)

def search(data, end_date):
    idx = bisect_left(data, end_date) - 1
    return data[idx] if idx >= 0 else 'No matching'

search(data, '2020/01/03')
# '2020/01/02'
```

If the data is not large, your original thought is totally fine.